Is this set closed, despite being union of an open and a closed set?
I'm perhaps losing myself in a glass of dirty water but I have a weird doubt. Is the set $(0, 1) \cup \mathbb{N}$ closed?
I mean if I had $[0, 1] \cup \mathbb{N}$, then I would know that it's closed since it's a finite union of closed sets.
On the other side, $\partial (0, 1) = \{0; 1\} \subset (0, 1) \cup \mathbb{N}$ (my definition of the Natural set contains the zero). So the set is closed because it does contain its boundary. Yet $(0, 1) \cup \mathbb{N}$ is not a union of closed sets.
On the other side again, I think of $[0, 1) \cup [1, 3] = [0, 3]$ which is indeed closed...
It puzzles me. But anyway, am I failing somewhere?

$ (0, 1) \cup \mathbb{N} = [0, 1] \cup \mathbb{N}$ (assuming that your definition of the natural numbers includes zero).

@MartinR This incredibly solves everything, and I thank you so much!

The conclusion that puzzes you goes only in one direction ("sufficient condition"). Note: Both of the sets $\mathbb Q$ and $\mathbb R\setminus\mathbb Q$ are neither open nor closed, yet their union is both open and closed, and also their intersection is both open and closed.

Just to be clear, we're talking about the usual order topology on $\mathbb{R}$, correct?

@MatthewLeingang Yes, sorry I forgot to mention. Usual standard topology in $\mathbb{R}$

@HagenvonEitzen Indeed another counter-example. Thanks!

@J.N. As a general counterexample, if $U$ is open, then $U\cup \partial U$ is the closure of $U$.
